# Python: I am working on a Restaurant tip calculator, I am trying to integrate radio buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I need to know how to implement the selected radio button into my calculations. Thanks for any and all help! I'm really not positive what the problem is, my only quest really comes from the "def selection" part. I just don't know what to do there

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.headerFont = ("Times", "16", "italic")
         self.title("Restaurant Tipper")
        self.addOrigBill()
        self.addChooseOne()
        self.addPercTip()
        self.addRateTip()
        self.addOutput()

    def addOrigBill(self):
        Label(self, text = "Bill Amount",
            font = self.headerFont).grid(columnspan = 1)
        self.txtBillAmount = Entry(self)
        self.txtBillAmount.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.txtBillAmount.insert(0,"100.00")

    def addChooseOne(self):
        Label(self, text = "Pick ONE! Choose your % of Tip or Rate your experience",
            font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    def addPercTip(self):
        Label(self, text = "% of Tip", 
            font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 3, column = 0)

        self.radPercTip1 = Radiobutton(self, text = "15%", 
            variable = self.percVar, value = .15, command = self.selected)
        self.radPercTip2 = Radiobutton(self, text = "17%", 
            variable = self.percVar, value = .17, command = self.selected)
        self.radPercTip3 = Radiobutton(self, text = "20%", 
            variable = self.percVar, value = .20, command = self.selected)

        self.radPercTip1.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        self.radPercTip2.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        self.radPercTip3.grid(row = 6, column = 0)

    def selected(self):
        float(self.percVar.get())

    def addRateTip(self):
        Label(self, text = "Tip by rating").grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        Label(self, text = "1 being the worst").grid(row = 4, column = 3)
        Label(self, text = "10 being the best").grid(row = 5, column = 3)
        Label(self, text = "Experience").grid(row = 6, column = 2)

        self.txtExperience = Entry(self)
        self.txtExperience.grid(row = 6, column = 3)

    def addOutput(self):
        self.btnCalc = Button(self, text = "Calculate Tip")
        self.btnCalc.grid(row = 7, columnspan = 2)
        self.btnCalc["command"] = self.calculate

        Label(self, text = "Tip").grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        self.lblTip = Label(self, bg = "#ffffff", anchor = "w", relief = "ridge")
        self.lblTip.grid(row = 8, column = 2, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Total Bill").grid(row = 9, column = 1)
        self.lblTotalBill = Label(self, bg = "#ffffff", anchor = "w", relief = "ridge")
        self.lblTotalBill.grid(row = 9, column = 2, sticky = "we")


    def calculate(self):
        bill = float(self.txtBillAmount.get())
        percTip = self.percVar
        rateTip = int(self.addRateTip.get())

        tip = bill * percTip
        self.lblTip["text"] = "%.2f" % tip

        totalBill = tip + bill
        self.lblTotalBill["text"] = "%.2f" % totalBill

        if rateTip <= 2:
            percTip = .10

        elif 3 <= rateTip <= 4:
            percTip = .12

        elif 5 <= rateTip <= 6:
            percTip = .15

        elif 7 <= rateTip <= 8:
            percTip = .17

        elif 9 <= rateTip <= 10:
            percTip = .20

        else:
            self.lblTotalBill["text"] = "Something is wrong"
def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I always get an error when I run the program, it is telling me that it is coming from somewhere in the addPercTip section. I just cannot find where from exactly.

Comment: It tells you it comes from "somewhere"? Or, does it tell you exactly where it comes from? Please show the complete traceback. It almost always tells you exactly the line with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `self.percVar` in your code. As @wastl said, you need to initialize it.

To do that, you need to use one of the [variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Since you are using `float` type, `DoubleVar()` would be the best.

```
def addPercTip(self):
    self.percVar = DoubleVar()  #this line should be added in your method
    Label(self, text = "% of Tip", 
        font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 3, column = 0)

def selected(self):
    print (type(self.percVar.get())) 
    #which is float, without converting explicitly because of DoubleVar()
    print (self.percVar.get())
    #this will print what you click
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to intialize the `self.percVar` variable

Add `self.percVar = 0` as the first line of the `addPercTip` method. That should fix your error.

BTW: For future questions the best thing is to include the error message you get and EXACTLY describe what part of the programm causes what kind of trouble for you